# Close login form on successful validation

Tags: c#

So i have a forms app that has to be in C#...

anyhow, im having trouble with my login screen.

the whole damned app is done except for this darn thing.

after a successful login the login window stands and hovers. HOW DO I GET RID OF IT!?

this is what i have so far

```
var MainMenu = new SwimmingApp.MainMenu();
var loginS = new Login();

loginS.Hide();
MainMenu.Show();
```

i also tried application.exit.

also, i have these two forms in two different projects in one solution.

THanks

Comment: Have you tried application exit on login.cs after validation?

Comment: The login form is the startupform, it loads first.

Comment: do you close the login form?

Comment: show some code for the love of God

Comment: The form doesnt close, if i close it by hitting the exit icon(top right of window), the whole entire app closes.

Comment: why creating new instance of Login then hiding it (without showing) instead of this.hide() ?

Comment: like i said, Login is the startup form, i dont declare an instance of it. its done naturally

Comment: thats to show what i have tried, its follewed by loginS.hide(),

Comment: are you showing MainMenu from inside Login Class ? If that's the case , just use this.hide().

Comment: i do declare an instance of MainMenu from within the login class

Comment: Then just use this.Hide() after MainMenu.Show();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem :** You are creating a new instance of the LoginForm and trying to hide that instead of hiding the already existing LoginForm.

**Solution :** You have to get the instance of existing or already loaded(into memory) Login form and hide it.

Try This:

```
Login frmLogin =(Login) Application.OpenForms["Login"];
frmLogin.Hide();
```

Comment: i get an Object reference not set to an instance of an object. error on the frmLogin.Hide();

Comment: @Jonny: you need to specify the proper form name in `OpenForms[]` array

Answer (score -1):

Inside Login method you can use

```
DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
```

Or outside Login you can use

```
loginS.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
```

Comment: I suppose was a popup... was a usercontrol?